# fix a component under react js and bootstrapp while allowing it to scroll vertically

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

The problem described is related to a React JS and Bootstrap project. The user has a component called "Home" that is inside a container. The component displays properly on a computer, but on mobile devices, it is not fixed and cannot be scrolled vertically. The user is seeking a solution to fix the component and enable vertical scrolling. The provided code includes a container with conditional padding based on the screen size, a navigation bar, and the "Home" component passed through the "children" prop. The "Home" component has a main element with various classes, including conditional styling for mobile devices. Additional code is not provided.

I tried to change the size of home to 100% but it disorganizes the desktop version and is still not fixed... I fixed home with "fixed" but it also disorganizes and no longer scrolls in mobile.

Comment: please I'm waiting some help

Comment: please add your tried code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.